# Subtracting long numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, long-integer, subtraction

Why is q == 0 in the following script?

```
<script>
  var start = 1234567890123456789;
  var end =   1234567890123456799;
  var q = end - start;
  alert(q);
</script>
```

I would think the result should be 10.  What is the correct way to subtract these two numbers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because numbers in JavaScript are floating-point. They have limited precision.

When JavaScript sees a very long number, it rounds it to the nearest number it can represent as a 64-bit float. In your script, `start` and `end` get rounded to the same value.

```
alert(1234567890123456789);   // says: 1234567890123456800
alert(1234567890123456799);   // says: 1234567890123456800
```

There's no built-in way to do precise arithmetic on large integers, but you can use a BigInteger library such as [this one](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/).

Answer (score 4):

As of January 2020, `BigInt` datatype is going to be added to Javascript. The proposal is currently in [Stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint). **It will enable precise calculation for number which are more than 2^53-1 (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).**

BigInt has been shipped in Chrome, Node, Firefox, and is underway in Safari. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

```js
var start = BigInt('1234567890123456789');
var end = BigInt('1234567890123456799');
var q = end - start;
alert(q)
```

A BigInt is created by appending n to the end of an integer literal — `10n` — or by calling the function BigInt(). It is also different from Number so 1 + 1n will fail.

You can read more about it here from [MDN pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Answer (score 3):

Jason already posted the why.  For a solution, you can get a Javascript BigInt library at http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/

Comment: @MicahelBray you should post the above as a comment to Jasons' answer.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const subtract = (a, b) => [a, b].map(n => [...n].reverse()).reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, d, i) => {
    let s = d - (b[i] || 0)
    if (s < 0) {
        s += 10
        a[i + 1]--
    }
    return '' + s + r
}, '').replace(/^0+/, ''))
```

Better use big-integer library for these things so as to handle all different test cases.

This is just for the a general case you can use....

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type):

> According to the ECMAScript standard, there is only one number type: [the double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) (numbers between `-(2`<sup>`53`</sup>`-1)` and `2`<sup>`53`</sup>`-1`). **There is no specific type for integers.**

Wikipedia page about [double precision floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) explains:

> Between `2`<sup>`52`</sup>`= 4,503,599,627,370,496` and `2`<sup>`53`</sup>`= 9,007,199,254,740,992` the representable numbers are exactly the integers. For the next range, from `2`<sup>`53`</sup> to `2`<sup>`54`</sup>, everything is multiplied by `2`, so the representable numbers are the even ones, etc.

*(All integer numbers smaller than `2`<sup>`52`</sup> are represented exactly.)*

`1234567890123456789` and `1234567890123456799` are larger than `2`<sup>`60`</sup>`= 1152921504606846976`. At this magnitude only about 1% of the integer numbers are stored exactly using the double-precision floating point format.

These two cannot be stored exactly. They both are rounded to `1234567890123456800`.

---

The [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type) also explains how to tell if a an integer number is stored exactly:

> [...] and starting with ECMAScript 6, you are also able to check if a number is in the double-precision floating-point number range using [`Number.isSafeInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) as well as [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) and [`Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER). Beyond this range, integers in JavaScript are not safe anymore and will be a double-precision floating point approximation of the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(x, y) {
    //*********************************************************************//
    // This function adds or subtracts two extremely large decimal numbers //
    // Inputs x and y should be numbers, i.e. commas are removed already   //
    // Use this function to remove commas and convert to number:           //
    // x = parseFloat(strNumber.replaceAll(",","").trim());                //
    // Inputs x and y can be both positive, or both negative,              //
    // or a combination (i.e. one positive and one negative in any         //
    // position whether as x or as y) which means subtraction              //
    //*********************************************************************//

    var temp, borrow=false, bothNeg=false, oneNeg=false, neg=false;
    if (x < 0 && y < 0) { bothNeg = true; x = -x; y = -y; } 
    else if (x < 0 || y < 0) {
        oneNeg = true;
        if (Math.abs(x) == Math.abs(y)) { x = 0; y = 0; }
        else if (x < 0 && Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y)) { neg = true; x = -x; y = -y; }
        else if (x < 0 && Math.abs(x) < Math.abs(y)) { temp = y; y = x; x = temp; }
        else if (y < 0 && Math.abs(x) < Math.abs(y)) { neg = true; temp = y; y = -x; x = -temp; }
    }
    x = parseInt(x*1000000000/10).toString();
    y = parseInt(y*1000000000/10).toString();
    var lenx=x.length, leny=y.length, len=(lenx>leny)?lenx:leny, sum="", div=0, x1, y1, rem;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        x1 = (i >= lenx) ? 0 : parseInt(x[lenx-i-1]);
        y1 = (i >= leny) ? 0 : parseInt(y[leny-i-1]);
        y1 = (isNaN(y1)) ? 0 : y1;
        if (oneNeg) y1 = -y1;
        if (borrow) x1 = x1 - 1;
        if (y < 0 && x1 > 0 && Math.abs(x1) >= Math.abs(y1)) { borrow=false; div=0; }
        if (y < 0 && y1 <= 0 && (x1 < 0 || Math.abs(x1) < Math.abs(y1))) { borrow=true; rem=(x1+y1+div+10)%10; div=10; }
        else { rem=(x1+y1+div)%10; div=Math.floor((x1+y1+div)/10); }
        sum = Math.abs(rem).toString() + sum;
    }
    if (div > 0) sum = div.toString() + sum;
    sum = parseFloat(sum*10/1000000000);
    if (bothNeg || neg) sum = -sum;
    return sum;
}
```