# Comparing large numbers with javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subtracting long numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050111/subtracting-long-numbers-in-javascript)

Can anyone tell me how to compare large numbers in javascript?

Something like

```
var sla = 1263293940000;
var resp = 1263296389700;

if(sla > resp)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653131/what-programming-language-will-enable-me-to-enter-a-very-long-number-without-conv/1653142#1653142

Comment: Dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964139/huge-integer-javascript-library

Comment: Also very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050111/subtracting-long-numbers-in-javascript which was just posted yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into the [BigInteger](http://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger) library.

Comment: This function is also working for me.                                                                    function numbersSort(lang, numbers) {
  numbers.sort(new Intl.Collator(lang,{numeric:true}).compare);
  return numbers;
}

console.log(numbersSort(this, ['12345678901234567890','1234567890123456789','123456789012345678']));
// expected output: Array ["123456789012345678", "1234567890123456789", "12345678901234567890"]

Answer (score 1):

Internally all javascript numbers are represented as double-precision floating point numbers. As you've discovered, this causes some rounding errors for very large numbers (and in other places). If you need more precision, you'll need to use a library like the one Alex posted.

Answer (score 1):

return new Number(first)>new Number(second);

Answer (score -4):

**return ('12345678901234568.13') <= ('12345678901234568.12');**