# In JavaScript, why ( Number.MAX_VALUE - 1) < Number.MAX_VALUE always evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, constants

In `JavaScript`, [Number.MAX_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) represents the maximum representable numeric value (which is approximately `1.79E+308`, a pretty big number)

However, if I evaluate `(Number.MAX_VALUE - 1) < Number.MAX_VALUE` in javascript console, it returns me `false`.

If i use multiplication, it works thought :

`(Number.MAX_VALUE * 0.99999) < Number.MAX_VALUE` returns `true`

Maybe I am missing something, but what is the possible explanation for this ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2050122/3274484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that although the allowable number range is *very* large, the precision of a JS number (IEEE 754 double precision) is insufficient to exactly represent every possible number in that range.  Doing so would require 308 digits!

Hence `MAX_VALUE - 1` is indistinguishable from `MAX_NUMBER`.

Comment: Does it means that if i would remove a very very small value from MAX_VALUE constant, it would work ?

Comment: @tigrou it would need to be a value sufficiently large to change the 53 bit (~15 - 17 digit) mantissa of the floating point representation.  It would actually be a very very large value - something like 1E+291!

Comment: Yes you are right it shoult rather be a large value. It seems to works with 1E+292.

Comment: Indeed - `MAX_VALUE - 1E+291 === MAX_VALUE` but `MAX_VALUE - 1E+292` does not.